# I need to calculate the number of signs in the first field in a file and sum them by another field

Tags: linux, bash

everyone. So I'm working with a .csv file in Linux environment and things are mostly progressing as planned. The file contains names and the year they're given and the gender assigned to them, for example:

```
"Pasi","1917","1"  
"Juha","1918","1"  
"Katri","1918","2"  
"Senna","1948","2"  
etc.
```

For the purposes of this task, the number denoting gender is irrelevant. I'd need to calculate the grand total sum of characters in the names by year. I figured I could easily `cut -d " -f 2 | awk '{ print length($0); }`' and then Paste the remaining paragraphs back since the number of lines remains the same. The problem remains that I'd need to get the sum by the year, which I can't seem to figure out how to do easily in Bash.

I'm running on a system where I have limited access so it would be less hassle if I could do it with just Bash commands. It feels like I should be able to do this pretty easily with Awk or Perl but I'm quite inexperienced so I can't sort my way out through this thing. Help

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Is the list ordered by year, as in your example?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest:

In this case:  
`"4","1917"   
"9","1918"  
"5","1948"`  
   
More generally, "character count","year" for all values of the year.

@user unknown: List ordered by years, yes.

@jww: Please pardon me. The code I listed is as far as I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution of the problem in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# get the data file as a command line argument
my $csv_file = shift;

open my $fh, $csv_file or die "Can't open $csv_file: $!";

# a hash to hold total names length per year
my %total_len;

while (<$fh>) {
    my ( $name, $year, $gender ) = split ",";

    # remove quotes
    $name =~ s/"//g;
    $year =~ s/"//g;

    $total_len{$year} += length $name;
}

# generate report sorted by year    
for my $year ( sort keys %total_len ) {
    print join( "\t", $year, $total_len{$year} ), "\n";
}
```

Save the code above in a file named `names_length` and the data in `data.csv` and run it like:

```
$ perl names_length data.csv 
1917    4
1918    9
1948    5
```

In case you prefer a one-liner:

```
cat data.csv | perl -pe 's/"//g' | perl -MData::Dumper -F"," -lane '$total{@F[1]} += length @F[0] }{ print Dumper \%total'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to sum the length of first fields year wise. If that's then below is the **awk**

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]+=length($1)-2} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Comment: Aye, that's exactly it. Thanks!